Setting Timezone for django connection
The Problem:
Postgresql timezone is set to 'UTC'
/etc/postgresql/15/main/conf.d/local.conf:
log_timezone = Europe/Warsaw
timezone = UTC

database has been altered:
ALTER DATABASE example_database SET TIMEZONE TO 'Europe/Warsaw';

Postgresql user has set own time_zone
SELECT rolconfig FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = 'someuser';
{TimeZone=Europe/Warsaw}

settings.py
USE_TZ = True
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Warsaw'

but during connection postgresql is getting:
 LOG:  statement: SELECT set_config('TimeZone', 'UTC', false)

What am I doing wrong???

FOUND IT!!!
I have to deep dive to postgresql libraries and found this:
/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py:
def timezone(self):
    """
    Return a tzinfo of the database connection time zone.

    This is only used when time zone support is enabled. When a datetime is
    read from the database, it is always returned in this time zone.

    When the database backend supports time zones, it doesn't matter which
    time zone Django uses, as long as aware datetimes are used everywhere.
    Other users connecting to the database can choose their own time zone.

    When the database backend doesn't support time zones, the time zone
    Django uses may be constrained by the requirements of other users of
    the database.
    """
    if not settings.USE_TZ:
        return None
    elif self.settings_dict["TIME_ZONE"] is None:
        return datetime.timezone.utc
    else:
        return zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(self.settings_dict["TIME_ZONE"])

And the solution is:
settings.py:
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2','postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
            'NAME': env('DATABASE_NAME'),
            # Not used with sqlite3.
            'USER': env('DATABASE_USER'),
            # Not used with sqlite3.
            'PASSWORD': env('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
            # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
            'HOST': env('DATABASE_HOST', default='127.0.0.1'),
            # Set to empty string for default.
            'PORT': env('DATABASE_PORT', default='5432'),
            'TIME_ZONE': 'Europe/Warsaw',

            # Not used with sqlite3.
        },

look at the additional parameter 'TIME_ZONE': 'Europe/Warsaw' in databases settings....
